# Service worker with create react app js chunks was loaded wrongly

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, react-loadable

I am using Create react app and service worker. However, sometimes when I build a new version, some js chunks was still loaded from service worker which they are not supposed to? And instead of loading a js file, it actually loads a html. After clear cache and reload the page, everything works fine.

1. I didn't cache the service worker on Nginx. Every time I refresh the page, the service worker file was loaded from the server.
2. I am using react-loadable

How do I solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, what I found is on my server I redirect everything to index.html, so when browser requests missing chunk, it receives index.html, causing `Unexpected token <` issue.

Comment: @fen1ksss If the chunk is missing, how do you handle the missing files? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @BruceMu did you find any solution for this..?

Answer (score 1):

As of you mentioned `react-loadable`, I'm assuming you are using async component loading in your application. If that is true, you are probably facing the same problem I did.

Whenever the new build is shipped, the new service worker is about to be installed. By default it will not be activated until the session is finished (all tabs/browser close). In order to activate it right away, `skipWaiting` parameter is used and set in `sw-precache-webpack-plugin` of `create-react-app` webpack config. So now, the old service worker and all related cached files will be removed since a new service worker is taking the responsibilities. This is fine in most cases, but not when we are dealing with async component loading. For that case we don't want old chunks to be removed since our app is reference them. To achieve that, we need to set `skipWaiting: false` in `sw-precache-webpack-plugin`.

More information could be found in [this](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/180#issuecomment-248386760) thread.